# How to write a Windows WIA(Windows Image Acquisition) driver?

Tags: sti, wia

Could anyone help me please? I'm totally confused.

I'm asked to write a Windows WIA driver. From MSDN (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/image/), I got some info:

> A WIA driver builds on the foundation provided by STI and so exposes STI interfaces in addition to its own. At a minimum, a WIA driver must expose the IStiUSD interface.

So, should I write a STI driver first? I don't know how to get started with STI neither. And, could a USB scanner work out of box with only INF files?

Answer (score 0):

What kind of hardware are you targetting? If you're interested in the driver for Camera device, you'd better use avstream driver.

Jesse Ahn

Comment: Thanks for reply. I'm now focusing on Scanner devices.